# Insert array-values to object angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have an array with values. I want to insert this values, into an object in angular. How is this insertion made? Is it possible to "transform" an array with values, to an object with the same values?

Comment: Please add some code.  Angular is just javascript so  you've not asked an angular question but a simple  javascript one.

Comment: you need to be a little more specific.

Comment: What is supposed to be object's keys after tranforming from array to object?

Comment: would it have been too much effort to create a simple sample of a before and after before asking the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use such a value like an array in more than one controller, you can use a simple value service or if it is a constant use the constant service.

For example you can do:

`angular.module('myApp').value('myArray', ['one', 'two']);`

or if a constant:

`angular.module('myApp').constant('myArray', ['one', 'two']);`

which you can use as a dependency in other controllers or services like

`app.controller('MyController', function($scope, myArray) {});`

Comment: I see, this is an object in angular! You have made a good guess :)

Answer (score 0):

You would place the object in your controller.

Something like so:

```
angular.module('myControllers',[]).controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.arrayWithValues = ['angular','is','great'];

}]);
```

Here's the official tutorial if you need a nice starting point.

**https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial**

I recommend to take the time to do the exercise as its worth it and really helped me.